# How does Rust call APIs that deal in C 'int'?

Tags: rust, integer

In place of C's motley collection of integer types accrued over the decades, Rust has a clear and orderly set of signed and unsigned integer types, such as `i32` for a signed 32-bit integer; on most platforms, this is also what C's `int` represents, though C does not guarantee this.

What happens when Rust is trying to call an API defined, not in terms of an absolute integer size, but in terms of "C `int`, whatever that may be on this platform"? For example, the classic Unix file I/O (`read`, `write` etc) that identifies files by small integers; on most platforms, these are signed 32-bit integers, but portable C code would normally refer to these as `int` (not `int32_t`), because that's how that API is defined; it is at least theoretically possible that e.g. a future operating system might define `int` as 64-bit, and bring that API along for the ride.

How does portable Rust code handle it? Does it just take the attitude that `i32` matches the platforms in use today, and that's good enough? Or does it do something else?

Comment: as always it's "best guess"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What happens when Rust is trying to call an API defined, not in terms of an absolute integer size, but in terms of "C int, whatever that may be on this platform"?

Rust defines the `c_int` type and various other [C type aliases used in FFI declarations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/raw/index.html) in the `raw::os` namespace to support this. This module uses `cfg` directives to detect the platform and architecture and [define these types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/raw/type.c_int.html) appropriately to match the equivalent C types. These exist for `int`, `long`, etc.

In this way, by using these neutral declarations, your code remains portable when rebuild on a different platform where C's `int` may vary.

> How does portable Rust code handle it? Does it just take the attitude that i32 matches the platforms in use today, and that's good enough? Or does it do something else?

[The `libc` module](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc) [defines its own c_int](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.99/libc/type.c_int.html) which does assume `i32`, presumably for historical reasons.  There is [an interesting RFC which details `libc`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1291-promote-libc.md) and its evolution.

> it is at least theoretically possible that e.g. a future operating system might define int as 64-bit

Certainly; in which case, a `#cfg[]` clause could be added for this OS to make it 64-bit, preserving source compatibility for the module.